# rbind + setkey in data.table slower than xts::rbind which automatically indexes?

Tags: r, data.table, xts

What is the reason behind `data.table` being almost 6x slower than `xts` when updating(=rbind) new rows?

```
library(quantmod); library(xts); library(data.table)
XTS = getSymbols("AAPL", from="2000-01-01", env = NULL)

# make corresponding `data.table`:
DT <- as.data.table(as.data.frame(XTS))
DT[, Date:=index(XTS)]
setkey(DT,Date)
setcolorder(DT,c("Date",names(XTS)))

# Note: rerun the above before running each test.
system.time(for(i in 1:10) XTS = rbind(XTS, XTS)) # reindexing is automatic
#    user  system elapsed 
#    0.15    0.03    0.47 
system.time(for(i in 1:10) DT = setkey(rbind(DT, DT), Date)) # need to manually reset key
#    user  system elapsed 
#    0.64    0.02    2.30 
system.time(for(i in 1:10) DT = setkey(rbindlist(list(DT, DT)), Date)) # ditto
#    user  system elapsed 
#    0.60    0.02    2.20
```

The `data.table` (unlike xts) will even exhaust memory allocation for i>15 on my computer.

The common programming use case is when you are running a temporal simulation and want to collect intermediate measurements into a result table, which you later want to summarise.

Comment: Where can I install `blotter` from?

Comment: @Arun ah, sorry, `quantmod` instead of `blotter` - it's just to get data quickly via `quantmod::getSymbols`. I edited the question.

Comment: Can't you collect them first, and bind + setkey once finally, like Beasterfield has shown? I see that `rbind.xts` is implemented in C, and if the reindexing is done in the same step, then it does it more efficiently. In DT, we've to bind first, then rearrange it. I'd try to avoid using it in this manner. Do you *have to* update this way?

Comment: @Arun, Unfortunately, the simulation needs to collect feedback from the summarized DT at each step and reparametrize itself. This is path-dependent simulation by design, next step depends on previous step

Comment: I guess `rbindlist` should then implement an additional `key` argument to return results in the sorted order already. I'm not sure how else you can get the same performance as xts::rbind

Comment: @Arun I agree that this requires C implementation, xts is a good benchmark for that. Perhaps feature request?

Comment: Yes, if you can file one (linking to this post), it'd be great! Maybe the title "rbind + setkey in data.table slower than xts::rbind which automatically indexes" is better?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
rbindlist( rep( list(DT), 10 ))
```

`rbindlist` should boost your runtime significantly.

Comment: Please note that each step of the simulation needs to gather feedback from each intermediate summary of `DT`, therefore `rbindlist( rep( list(DT), 10 ))` is not the same as `DT = setkey(rbindlist(list(DT, DT)), Date)`

Comment: I've also added third test with `rbindlist`, and the improvement is only marginal